# Oracle 12c import dump with user profiles & roles

Tags: oracle, roles, profile, datapump, impdp

I'm trying to import dump file I received from customer.

The customer defined the schema on user with Profile and Role which obviously do not exist in my Database and are not required by me.

Whenever I do impdp I get multiple errors:

```
ORA-02380: profile APPL_PROFILE does not exist
ORA-01919: role 'APP_ROLE' does not exist
```

Is there a way to exclude the roles and profile from the import?
The only way I find to handle it is creating this Profile and role in my Database - which is not required and would like to avoid.

Comment: See the EXCLUDE option to skip over various object types - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-DC7668E1-C846-48C5-A0D5-F4659EC119BB.htm#SUTIL911

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do that with exclude:user exclude:grant

as suggested here 
https://www.cnblogs.com/chendian0/p/10867504.html